# How to use independence to simplify $E\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu ) \right\}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, expectation

I don't know how to get the second line from the first line in the following:
[image]

In the above case, $Y=(y_1, \dots , y_n)^T$ is a random sample from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

My trouble is in simplifying $ E\left(\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu )  \right\}^2\right)$. What I've tried:

$$ \begin{align} 
E\left(\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu )  \right\}^2\right) & = E\left(\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu )  \right\}\right) E\left(\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu )  \right\}\right) , \text{ by independence} \\
& = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n E \left( Y_i - \mu \right) \right)^2 \text{ by linearity of expectations}
\end{align}$$

I don't see how I can get the variance from here on wards. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: $\sum(Y_i-\mu)$ is not independent from itself so the equality there is wrong. Use the fact that $(\sum (y_i-\mu))^2 = \sum(y_i-\mu)^2 +\sum_{i\neq j}{(y_i-\mu)(y_j-\mu)}$. Independence will work for the second sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, write $X_i=Y_i-\mu$, such that $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0$.
Then, 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\right] 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right)\right] 
= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n X_i X_j\right] \\
&= \sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n} \mathbb{E}[X_i X_j] \tag{linearity}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]  + \sum_{1\leq i\neq j \leq n} \mathbb{E}[X_i]\mathbb{E}[X_j] \qquad\text{(independence when $i\neq j$)} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]  + 0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var} Y_i = n\mathrm{Var} Y_1
\end{align}$$

Comment: in the first line, last equality, shouldn't $X_j X_j$ be $X_i X_j$?

Comment: same case with the second line as well?

Comment: and the third. The three typos are gone.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying out 
$$
E\left[\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\mu ) \right\}^2\right]
$$
You get terms like
$$
E\left[(Y_i-\mu )^2\right]
$$
as shown, but also terms like
$$
2E\left[(Y_i-\mu )(Y_j-\mu )\right]
$$
for $i<j$.  But the independence shows
$$
E\left[(Y_i-\mu )(Y_j-\mu )\right] = E\left[(Y_i-\mu )\right] E\left[(Y_j-\mu )\right]
$$
and $\mu$ was chosen so that these are all zero.